# how to use Spring RestTemplate in Servlet?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, servlets, jakarta-ee

I am trying to use RestTemplate in my Servlet project.I have a some values to send to Restful Web service. I have tried the below code:

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
 String url = "http://localhost:8080/spring-rest/data/putdata{id}{name}";
 Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
 map.put("id", "100");
 map.put("name", "Ram");
 Address address = new Address("Dhananjaypur", "Varanasi","UP");
 restTemplate.put(url, address, map);
```

The version of the jar I am using spring-web-4.39-RELEASE.jar. when i try to debug the application I am getting the below Exception:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate
```

But I already added the jar file in classpath. can any one help me on this?

Comment: https://jira.spring.io/browse/ANDROID-78 - from 2012

Answer (score 0):

It's definatley there, are you sure you have the jar in your repo, and you using 
spring-web-4.3.9-RELEASE.jar and not spring-web-4.39-RELEASE.jar

```
$ jar tvf spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar  | grep RestTemplate.class
 30116 Wed Jun 07 19:11:32 BST 2017 org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.class
```

Comment: I have added the jar file correctly giving the exception